# Rust Polars: How to use a function in groupby aggregation that produces multiple columns?

Tags: rust-polars

I want to apply a function on an `Expr` that produces multiple new columns.
Can this be achieved using Rust Polars?

Specifically, I want to calculate the linear regession fit (using the `linfa` and `linfa-linear` crates) to my data in the groupby operation.
At the moment I do it in two separate `apply` calls which means the calculation is done twice instead of once.

Below is the code I have at the moment:

```rust
fn _linear_fit_intercept(s: Series) -> Result<Option<Series>, PolarsError> {
    let arr = s
        .into_frame()
        .to_ndarray::<Float32Type>(IndexOrder::C)
        .unwrap();
    let arr = arr
        .remove_axis(Axis(1))
        .into_dimensionality::<Ix1>()
        .unwrap();
    let x = ndarray::Array::range(0., arr.len() as f32, 1.);
    let x = x.insert_axis(Axis(1));
    let dataset = Dataset::new(x, arr);
    let lin_reg = LinearRegression::new();
    let model = lin_reg.fit(&dataset).unwrap();
    let s_i = Series::new("intercept", &[model.intercept()]).into_series();
    //let s_p = Series::new("slope", &[model.params()[0]]).into_series(); <-- ideally I should return both of the intercept and the linear fit in the same function
    Ok(Some(s_i))
}

pub fn linear_fit_intercept(name: &str) -> Expr {
    let o = GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float32);
    col(name)
        .apply(_linear_fit_intercept, o)
        .cast(DataType::Float32)
        .get(0)
        .alias(&format!("{}_linear_fit_intercept", name))
}

fn _linear_fit_slope(s: Series) -> Result<Option<Series>, PolarsError> {
    let arr = s
        .into_frame()
        .to_ndarray::<Float32Type>(IndexOrder::C)
        .unwrap();
    let arr = arr
        .remove_axis(Axis(1))
        .into_dimensionality::<Ix1>()
        .unwrap();
    let x = ndarray::Array::range(0., arr.len() as f32, 1.);
    let x = x.insert_axis(Axis(1));
    let dataset = Dataset::new(x, arr);
    let lin_reg = LinearRegression::new();
    let model = lin_reg.fit(&dataset).unwrap();
    let s_p = Series::new("", &[model.params()[0]]).into_series();
    Ok(Some(s_p))
}

pub fn linear_fit_slope(name: &str) -> Expr {
    let o = GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Float32);
    col(name)
        .apply(_linear_fit_slope, o)
        .cast(DataType::Float32)
        .get(0)
        .alias(&format!("{}_linear_fit_slope", name))
}
```

The `linear_fit_intercept` and `linear_fit_slope` then are included in the `groupby` list of aggregators.

Can I combine the `linear_fit_intercept` and `linear_fit_slope` into one function `linear_fit` that returns multiple series?

I tried to write a function that returns a `DataFrame` instead of a series:

```rust
fn _linear_fit(s: Series) -> Result<DataFrame, PolarsError> {
    let arr = s
        .into_frame()
        .to_ndarray::<Float32Type>(IndexOrder::C)
        .unwrap();
    let arr = arr
        .remove_axis(Axis(1))
        .into_dimensionality::<Ix1>()
        .unwrap();
    let x = ndarray::Array::range(0., arr.len() as f32, 1.);
    let x = x.insert_axis(Axis(1));
    let dataset = Dataset::new(x, arr);
    let lin_reg = LinearRegression::new();
    let model = lin_reg.fit(&dataset).unwrap();
    let s_i = Series::new("intercept", &[model.intercept()]).into_series();
    let s_p = Series::new("slope", &[model.params()[0]]).into_series();
    DataFrame::new(vec![s_i, s_p])
}

pub fn linear_fit(name: &str) -> Expr {
    col(name)
        .apply(_linear_fit, None)
        .cast(DataType::Float32)
        .get(0)
        .alias(&format!("{}_linear_fit", name))
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work as `Expr`'s `apply` expects the function to return an `Result<Option<Series>, PolarsError>` as evidenced by the following errror:

```
 │     expected `_linear_fit` to be a fn item that returns `Result<Option<Series>, PolarsError>`, but it returns `Result<DataFrame, PolarsError>` rustc (E0271) [207, 16]
 │      expected enum `std::result::Result<std::option::Option<polars::prelude::Series>, _>` 
 │         found enum `std::result::Result<polars::prelude::DataFrame, _>`
```